# Function is in an infinite loop but should be blocked by foreach loops

Tags: c#

I have gotten this bug for a long time now: The goal of these two functions is to Combine all possible items that have the same attributes and check which one is the cheapest.

For ex.: You have an array of attributes and check one item, it does not meet the requirements so it redoes the loop for every single item except this one, so in theory, the auctionProducts list should stop once every single possible outcome has been made.

In my program it keeps looping and the auctionProducts count in parameters stays around 39 and only goes down by 1 and comes back up again by one. Could anyone help me on this one, I know this is not related to any exceptions or errors.

Edit: I found out the count of auctionProducts(39) that keeps revisiting is the count of products that have the requirements.

Here is the main function:

```
public static decimal AttributesPrice(this Dictionary<string, dynamic> attributes, List<AuctionProduct> auctionProducts, decimal basePrice, params string[] attributeNames)  //How does the loop keep going when it should be limited (auctionProducts*auctionProducts-1*auctionProducts-2*auctionProducts-3*auctionProducts-4)
       {
           var prices = new List<decimal>();

           foreach (var auctionProduct in auctionProducts)
           {
               if (attributes.HasValues(auctionProduct.Items.Entries[0].Tag.Attributes, attributeNames))
               {
                   prices.Add(auctionProduct.Info.StartingBid - basePrice);
               }
               else
               {
                   prices.Add(attributes.Subtract(auctionProduct.Items.Entries[0].Tag.Attributes).MergeAttributes(auctionProduct, auctionProducts.Reranged(auctionProduct), basePrice, attributeNames));
               }
           }

           Console.WriteLine(auctionProducts.Count());
Output:
39
37
37
39
37
37
39
41
37
37
39
37
37
39
Keeps going on for infinite
           if (prices.Count() > 0)
               return prices.Min();

           return 0;
       }
```

Here is my function to merge attributes:

```
       private static decimal MergeAttributes(this Dictionary<string, dynamic> attributes, AuctionProduct auctionProduct, List<AuctionProduct> auctionProducts, decimal basePrice, string[] attributeNames)
       {
           var prices = new List<decimal>();

           foreach (var auctionComparer in auctionProducts)
           {
               if (attributes.HasValues(auctionComparer.Items.Entries[0].Tag.Attributes, attributeNames))
               {
                   prices.Add(auctionComparer.Info.StartingBid + auctionProduct.Info.StartingBid - basePrice * 2);
               }
               else
               {
                   prices.Add(attributes.AttributesPrice
                             (auctionProducts.Reranged(auctionComparer), basePrice, attributeNames) -
                              basePrice);
               }
           }

           if (prices.Count() > 0)
               return prices.Min();

           return 0;
       }
```

Here is my function Reranged(Is not the problem, I've had this before I added this):

```
public static List<AuctionProduct> Reranged(this List<AuctionProduct> list, params AuctionProduct[] items)
       {
           var buffer = new List<AuctionProduct>(list);
           foreach (var item in items)
               buffer.Remove(item);

           return buffer;
       }
```

Here is my function(It subtracts all values that aren't seen in a dictionary and works as intended)

```
public static Dictionary<string, dynamic> Subtract(this Dictionary<string, dynamic> dictionary, Dictionary<string, dynamic> subtractor )
        {
            dynamic compareOut;
            if (ValueComparing.Compare(subtractor, dictionary, out compareOut)) return null;
            else return (Dictionary<string, dynamic>)compareOut;
        }
```

Here is my function to check value(Works as intended)

```
        public static bool HasValues(this Dictionary<string, dynamic> attributes, Dictionary<string, dynamic> comparer,string[] attributeNames)
        {
            foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {
                if (!attributeNames.Contains(attribute.Key))
                {
                    if (!comparer.ContainsKey(attribute.Key))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (!ValueComparing.Compare(comparer[attribute.Key], attribute.Value))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Did you step through in a debugger? Did you write unit tests for the correct behavior?

Comment: I spend alot of time debugging, yes. I cannot find anything and this is pretty much all info  I  can give.

Comment: Your `AttributePrices` calls `MergeAttributes` and vice versa `MergeAttributes` calls `AttributePrices`. We can't check the conditions, under which this happens because your code is far from complete and you have not posted any example data. But there is a possibility, that these two call each other infinitely under certain conditions ...

Comment: Where's the rest of the AttributePrices function?